# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: linux, linux-mint, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am running the same Dockerfile on two basically identical Linux machines.
It works on one side, it fails on the other, with the message:

```
  standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I reduced the Dockerfile to a minimum:

```
FROM xxxx/debian:jessie_2017-03-23_armhf

CMD echo "Hello World"
```

## The system information of machine 1:

## docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:19:38 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Aug 15 15:12:41 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

## docker system info

```
Containers: 204
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 204
Images: 69
Server Version: 18.09.7
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 466
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 
runc version: N/A
init version: v0.18.0 (expected: fec36.....)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-154-generic
Operating System: Linux Mint 18.1
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.31GiB
Name: some_namx
ID: ABCU:F34S:12BA:1Y67:N692:HERA:SGTZ:1278:34O8:XZ45:2N6K:COHJ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 xxx.yyy.zzz.ab:1234
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

## Further information

```
dpkg -l | grep docker 
ii  docker                                1.5-1 amd64        System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications
rc  docker-engine                         17.05.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial                     amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine 
ii  docker.io                             18.09.7-0ubuntu1~16.04.5        amd64        Linux container runtime

dpkg --print-architecture amd64

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures i386

lscpu 
Architecture:          x86_64 CPU
op-mode(s):            32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) persocket:     4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1329.234
CPU max MHz:           4500.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              8399.90
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single intel_pt ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp kaiser tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Release:    18.1 
Codename:   serena

docker run golang go version go version go1.13.3 linux/amd64

docker run mplatform/mquery golang Image: golang  * Manifest List: Yes
* Supported platforms:
   - linux/amd64
   - linux/arm/v7
   - linux/arm64
   - linux/386
   - linux/ppc64le
   - linux/s390x
   - windows/amd64:10.0.14393.3274
   - windows/amd64:10.0.17134.1069
   - windows/amd64:10.0.17763.805
```

## The system information of machine 2:

## docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:19:38 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Aug 15 15:12:41 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

## docker system info

```
Containers: 262
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 262
Images: 160
Server Version: 18.09.7
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 734
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 
runc version: N/A
init version: v0.18.0 (expected: fec36....)
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-165-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.859GiB
Name: a_name
ID: 1246:XV56:89G5:O8AM:2W9A:LEGO:1HJS:WG1K:SKAN:EPOX:ONCA:CA24
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

## Further information:

```
dpkg | grep docker
ii  docker                                1.5-1                                           amd64        System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications
ii  docker.io                             18.09.7-0ubuntu1~16.04.5                        amd64        Linux container runtime

dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 79
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2096.015
BogoMIPS:              4192.03
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc pni pclmulqdq dtes64 ds_cpl ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single kaiser fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 bmi2 erms invpcid rtm xsaveopt cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local arat

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

docker run golang go version
go version go1.13.3 linux/amd64

docker run mplatform/mquery golang
Image: golang
 * Manifest List: Yes
 * Supported platforms:
   - linux/amd64
   - linux/arm/v7
   - linux/arm64
   - linux/386
   - linux/ppc64le
   - linux/s390x
   - windows/amd64:10.0.14393.3274
   - windows/amd64:10.0.17134.1069
   - windows/amd64:10.0.17763.805
```

The first one (on a Jenkins server) is working correctly, while the second one fails with the given error.
What could be the issue? I am out of ideas!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the tag on your image, it looks like you are trying to run ARM based binaries on a x86 based host. This typically won't work without something to interpret the binary. On Linux there's Qemu plus the binfmt_misc kernel module that provides this support. You also need the various static binfmt binaries from qemu to enable this per architecture.

On Debian the static binaries are available in the `qemu-user-static` package with one catch. At last check in stable, Debian doesn't load these binaries in a way that supports a chroot type of environment like you have in Debian, it will look for the qemu static binaries inside the container rather than using the files on the host. See [this issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868030) and consider installing the binaries in a different way or use an unstable version.

When you have everything configured correctly, you should see the following:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-arm
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
flags: OCF
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002002800
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

Two important things to look for, first that the binfmt_misc and qemu-arm directory and file exist. And second, that the flags section includes a `F` to indicate the binaries is fixed and won't be affected by the container root filesystem changing.

Comment: On the working machine (a Jenkins server) I have this:
cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-arm
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
flags: OC
offset 0
magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002002800
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff

apt-cache policy qemu
  Installed: (none)
  ...
libglib2.0-dev, libfdt-dev, libpixman-1-dev, zlib1g-dev not installed either.

On the non-working machine /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-arm does not exist.
I am totally a novice in this domain.
What do I need to do in order to have it running in the same way as on the Jenkins server.

Comment: Did you go through the process to install and configure `binfmt_misc` on the failing host. These steps tend to be distribution specific.

Comment: I found the problem: qemu-user-binfmt was conflicting with qemu-user-static.
Now I can find qemu-arm under /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
Unfortunately life is cruel and I still get an error:
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Comment: Does your /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/ file include both of the "important things" listed above?

Comment: The file does not have the F flag, but it doesn't have it either on the Jenkins server.

Comment: What is strange is that if my Dockerfile contains:
RUN apt-get xxxx instead of CMD echo Hello
I get the same error: standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
But this command has nothing to do with the guest OS, it is a command meant to generate the image in the current OS. 
I am confused...
When I change the FROM line to amd64 it works.

Comment: The file not found error is because you do not have the `F` flag. Without it, it is looking for the static binaries inside the container.

Comment: But why does it work on the other server then?

Comment: How can I set that flag?

Comment: Please take the time to actually read the answer posted above rather than asking me to repeat myself and ignoring the advice provided.

Comment: I found the reason... As I said above, qemu-user-binfmt and qemu-user-static conflicts. It is absolutely necessary to use qemu-user-static. Unfortunately I always installed 1st the user-static and then user-binfmt, which overwrote user-static. In my desperation, I just inverse the order and, oh wonder, it works!
Documentation is so poor, I didn't find a way to set this 'F' flag, but it seems it doesn't matter.

Comment: One sees the difference between the two in the __interpreter__ line when you `cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-arm`. When you install __user-static__ you will get **interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static** which is the **correct** setting, otherwise you'll have **interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm** which is **wrong**

Comment: @StubbornDonkey you likely have a `/use/bin/qemu-arm-static` file inside your container to make that work. As posted in the answer above, getting the `F` flag typically involves installing packages from a newer (unstable) release in both Debian and Ubuntu.